# How to remove spaces from a captured wildcard?

Tags: regex, notepad++, regex-group, regex-greedy, find-replace

I'm trying to alter some XML with Find&Replace in Notepad++ using regex.

This is the specific XML I'm trying to capture:

```
<category name="Content Server Categories:FOLDER:test category">
    <attribute name="test attribuut"><![CDATA[test]]></attribute>
    <attribute name="test attribuut1"><![CDATA[test1]]></attribute>
</category>
```

Following 'FIND' regex does the job (for now):

```
<(category) name="Content Server Categories:(.+?)">(.+)</(category)>
```

Now i need the XML to be replaced by this:

```
<category-FOLDER:testcategory name="Content Server Categories:FOLDER:test category">
    <attribute name="test attribuut"><![CDATA[test]]></attribute>
    <attribute name="test attribuut1"><![CDATA[test1]]></attribute>
</category-FOLDER:testcategory>
```

Currently i tried using this 'REPLACE BY' regex:

```
<($1-$2) name="Content Server Categories:($2)">($3)</($1-$2)>
```

But that gives to following output:

```
<category-FOLDER:test category name="Content Server Categories:FOLDER:test category">
    <attribute name="test attribuut"><![CDATA[test]]></attribute>
    <attribute name="test attribuut1"><![CDATA[test1]]></attribute>
</category-FOLDER:test category>
```

As you can see i get **category-FOLDER:test category**
instead of **category-FOLDER:testcategory**

The space(s) needs to be removed..

The problem is that the input can look different. Now it is this:

```
<category name="Content Server Categories:FOLDER:test category">
```

But it could look like these examples as well:

```
<category name="Content Server Categories:FOLDER1:FOLDER2:test category">

<category name="Content Server Categories:FOLDER NAME:test category">

<category name="Content Server Categories:FOLDER NAME: FOLDER NAME1:test category">

<category name="Content Server Categories:FOLDER:test category name">

...
```

How do I catch all of these correctly and remove the spaces?

EDIT: Almost forgot,

```
'. Matches newline' is __ON__
```

Comment: If there are always exactly two terms, just match `(\w+) (\w+)` and drop out the space. I don't think you can do generic replacements. Either use a proper scripting language, or do a two-step replacement where the second step removes all spaces between `<category-FOLDER:` and `name="`

Comment: There are not always exact 2 terms.. that is the problem..

Comment: What is the expected outcome of `<category name="Content Server Categories:FOLDER NAME: FOLDER NAME1:test category">`

Comment: @Thefourthbird <category-FOLDERNAME:FOLDERNAME1:testcategory name="Content Server Categories:FOLDER NAME: FOLDER NAME1:test category">

Comment: One approach with the multiple spaces to remove is to first get the desired structure using https://regex101.com/r/SzqKNI/1 and then replace the spaces using https://regex101.com/r/U9Lex5/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach could be to do it in 2 steps due to the replacement of the multiple spaces afterwards.

Get the required structure (Note to use the non greedy version `.*?` to prevent over matching):

```
<(category) name="Content Server Categories:(.+?)">(.+?)</(category)>
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SzqKNI/1)

In the replacement use your replacement without the parenthesis or else they would be included in the replacement:

```
<$1-$2 name="Content Server Categories:$2">$3</$1-$2>
```

Then match the spaces making use of repetitive matches using `\G`:

```
(?:</?category-|\G(?!^))\K\s*([\w:]+) (?!name=)
```

In the replacement replace the whitespaces with capturing group 1 `$1`

**Explanation**

- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `</?category-FOLDER` Match text with an optional `/`
  - `|` Or
  - `\G(?!^)` Assert position at the end of the previous match
- `)` Close non capturing group
- `\K\s*` Forget what was previously matched and then match 0+ whitespace chars
- `([\w:]+)` Capture in group 1 matching 1+ times a word char or :
- `(?!name=)` Assert what is on the right is not a not 'name='

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VYwj4c/1)

Comment: After i do the first replacement the next regex does not get a match: (?:^</?category-FOLDER|\G(?!^))\K\s*([\w:]+)(?!\S). I'm using Notepad++, maybe that is the problem?

Comment: I have tested it in notepad with the content in my example. Can you create an example on regex101 with your content? Or try it without `^`

Comment: @Michieldepaepe I have tested it in notepad++ with the content in my regex examples. Can you try it without the `^` like in this [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/VYwj4c/2) Or else can you share a regex101 link with the content for which you are trying?

Comment: That one almost does the trick! :) It's still not working for the closing part of my xml element..

Comment: @Michieldepaepe What exactly is not correct? Can you share the xml on regex101 so I can check?

Comment: </category-FOLDER:test category> Here 'test' and 'category' should not have a space between them as well. I think it is because your regex expects a space behind the word. Is it possible to make it so that the regex expects a space or '>'? then it will work i think?

Comment: This one looks like it does the trick, except when when the name attribute ends with 'name' :p

Comment: What is the rule for the last attribute? Is there always a `category`? What can come after it?

Comment: <**category name="Content Server Categories:**FOLDER:test category">
    <**attribute name="test attribuut"><![CDATA[test]]></attribute**>
    <**attribute name="test attribuut1"><![CDATA[test1]]></attribute**>
</**category**>

Comment: It's not very clear.. but everything between ** is always the same

Comment: @Michieldepaepe I used the negative lookahead `(?!name\b)` after the space so that what follows can not be `name` because the last property is either `name="` or `name>` But the issue is that there could be either `name>` or `category>` at the end so there is not really a way to distinguish between them not using `name`. See a [shortened example](https://regex101.com/r/mYWXUz/1/) to illustrate what I mean. That is why I asked what the logic for the last property could be to make a generic distinction.

Comment: I've been looking to it myself and i think this one does the trick:
(?:</?category-|\G(?!^))\K\s*([\w:]+) (?!name=)

Comment: @Michieldepaepe Nice, glad to hear that that pattern works!

Comment: Thanks for your help, could not have done it without!